# Button text gets cut off in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

The following HTML displays correctly in Chrome but not in IE.  The button text gets cut off.

```
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
      <TITLE>Button test</TITLE>
      <STYLE type="text/css">
      p { padding-left: 2em; text-indent: -2em }
      </STYLE>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY>
   <DIV style="margin-left: 0.5in; margin-right: 0.5in">First line<P>Second line<BUTTON>Button will be clicked</BUTTON>
   </DIV>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

The idea behind the `p` style entry is that I want paragraphs to appear with the first line to the left of the remaining lines.  I've reduced this to a minimal example, but normally there would be an onclick event set up for the `BUTTON`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that in IE, if the `BUTTON` occurs inside a `P`, the `text-indent` property of the paragraph element is inherited by the `BUTTON`, causing it to move the text to the left so that some of it drops off the button.  This can be solved by adding `style="text-indent: 0"` to the `BUTTON`, or adding this to the style sheet:

```
  button { text-indent: 0 }
```